# Model marginal and joint distributions from a sample of unkown number of categories

Tags: bayesian, categorical-data, entropy, frequentist, mutual-information

To illustrate the problems imagine I'm drawing labelled spheres from a box. I may or may not know the number of spheres in the box (does it make a difference?)

If I draw 10 spheres from the box and they are all different what did I learn about the distribution of the probability of drawing each label? They may be just 10 out of zillion other labels or maybe there exists exactly 10 labels and by luck we sampled exactly one of each.

A follow up question is when we have two boxes. We don't know if the draws from those boxes are independent or not. If I keep sampling pairs of labels that haven't shown up before we don't know if these labels were sampled by chance or not.

In case it matters or not: my final goal is to draw conclusions about entropy and mutual information

Comment: The two-box problem doesn't appear to differ at all from the one-box problem except in the physical model you propose: in both cases you are sampling from an unknown population.  And what contrast are you making in your follow-up question where in a single sentence you use "sampling pairs of labels" as if this were an *iid* sample but then refer to "sampled by chance or not"?  What exactly does the "or not" clause refer to?

Comment: What I mean is I don't know if the distributions of the two boxes are independent or not. In the physical model: if I sample once box1,2=(X,Y) idk if next time I sample box1=X it increases the probability box2=Y

Comment: In other words, I have a sample of a dataset with two categorical columns and unkown number of categories. One column is potentially a derivation of another. I would like to draw conclusions about marginal, joint probabilities, entropy and mutual information between these two columns

Comment: In the circumstance where there are no repetitions of values in either column, there's no way to test whether the columns are independent and there's exceptionally little that you can conclude, because you in effect have a collection of unique *pairs* of data.